# Full Text Catalog is destroyed after changes in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-catalog

**I'm facing a strange problem:** Everytime I make changes in tables (e.g. adding a column, altering a column's datatype, renaming a column, etc.) my full text catalog is being destroyed the moment I press "Save" in the SSMS.

After that, SSMS's properties dialog of the full text catalog shows a *catalog size* of 0 MB and an *item count* of 0. The only option I have after this is to rebuild the catalog.

Has anyone experienced the same or a similiar problem?

**Some additional info:**
SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2016 Management Studio

Thanks in advance and greetings from Austria! :)

SiJayBe

Comment: If you disable `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation` SSMS takes the *safest* approach to modifying tables which is to copy all data to a backup table then drop and rebuild the original table. The default is "enabled"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already thought of this option, I set it to "disabled" some time ago, as I often need to add new columns to my tables and with this option set to "enabled", it is very unpractically for me to do this.

Comment: Don't use SSMS if you don't want to use this behaviour, just use the appropriate DDL commands, or generate the script and modify it to avoid dropping the table

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try to do it that way. Another question: When a new version of our software is delivered to our customers, we're using SMO to alter the tables to the new definition. As far as I understand, SMO is used by the SSMS as well. So do you think I might run into the same problems concerning the full text catalog when altering the tables with SMO?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SMO. SMO is what generates the final code but it's the application or SSMS that actually decides what to do.